# ASP.Net Core app works in visual studio but not with dotnet run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core app that I started building through visual studio and normally it works fine when I press F5 or press the debug button in visual studio.

However, if I try to use `dotnet run` from command line, it still works and starts listening on the default port 5000 (I'm assuming this is kestrel listening). 
[image]

But if I try to access the page through any browser using http://localhost:5000, I just get error saying unable to connect. I understand that if I run from visual studio, it automatically puts my app behind IIS but I dont understand why it doesn't work if the app is just self hosted.

I want to move my project to a linux environment and this is the only thing that seems to be stopping me now. I've tested with creating new dotnet apps through cli and those work fine if I try to access through browser, it just seems that this specific app that I created in VS doesn't work.

My `dotnet --version` returns 1.0.4

## Edit (detailed answer)

So to add to Sanket's answer below, I also figured out the real reason why my app was only working if I had set my `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to Development.

It turns out that I had set a testing mail service to only be configured if my environment was Development like so:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
        WorldContextSeedData seeder)
    {

        if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); 
            loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);
        }
    }
```

But in one of my controllers I had initalized the mail service without checking the environment like so:

```
public AppController(IMailService mailService, IConfigurationRoot config, WorldRepository repository, ILogger<AppController> logger, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
    _mailService = mailService;
    _config = config;
    _repository = repository;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

I realized this problem when I decided to configure `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` for Staging environment and it became obvious as soon as I ran it where my issue was. My controller class was trying to initialize the mail service when it hadn't been configured in the first place. So I made some changes to my controller like so:

```
        public AppController(
#if Development
            IMailService mailService,
#endif
            IConfigurationRoot config, 
            IWorldRepository repository, ILogger<AppController> logger, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
#if Development
            _mailService = mailService;
#endif
            _config = config;
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

And now my app works in any environment.

Comment: Could you try with `dotnet YourProject.dll`? For example, `dotnet WordApp.dll`

Comment: Also check hosting environment variable. You may be running in Development in case of Visual Studio and in Production in case of dotnet cli.

Comment: @Sanket it turns out you were correct. Once I figured out how to set the environment variable to Development, it worked like a charm. Can you post as an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error occurred because value of **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** variable is different. In case of Visual Studio it was set to `Development` and in case of dotnet cli (as you can see in screenshot in question), it was `Production`.

To set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable using command line, use below command -

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

For more information on how to set hosting environment, please refer this [article](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/).