# Dotnet run doesn't work in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have an issues running net.core 2.0 app inside of vscode. I installed angular cli project, then used dotnet new webapi to install net.core 2.0 project.

Structure is like this:
[image]

When I use command dotnet run, I can see kestrel is running:

> PS D:\CodePlayground\my-dream-app> dotnet run Using launch settings
>   from D:\CodePlayground\my-dream-app\Properties\launchSettings.json...
>   Hosting environment: Development Content root path:
>   D:\CodePlayground\my-dream-app Now listening on:
>   http://localhost:28009

But when I open a page in browser I get this:
[image]

It works in visual studio 2017, iis or self hosted.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551787/asp-net-core-app-works-in-visual-studio-but-not-with-dotnet-run?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your controller like http://localhost:28009/yourcontrollername or you have to config which action for empty route