# Angular/NET Core Web API not getting hit while running using "dotnet run" command

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, routes

Angular newbie here. I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 based Angular 7.0 application. My Web APIs are not hit (always get a 404) if i run my app from a command line using `dotnet run`, but it gets hit properly when it is run directly from VS 2017 IISExpress (by pressing F5). Since the application works fine while an F5 run, i assume my `Startup.cs` settings are correct, still i am copying the route part here

```
    app.UseMvc(
        routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

I will be happy to provide more details, should you need them.

**Update 1**: I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551787/asp-net-core-app-works-in-visual-studio-but-not-with-dotnet-run) post and that was not applicable in my case.

**Update 2**: After further investigation, i have found out that upon executing `dotnet run`, three ports are opened

1. Non SSL port for ASP.NET (in my case 5000)
2. SSL port for ASP.NET (in my case 5001)
3. Non SSL port for `Angular CLI` (in my case 5002 -  i specifically
   asked for 5002 in  `package.json`)

If i make the Web API call to either 5000 or 5001 (both opened by ASP.NET), it works (while my Angular app is running in 5002!). So the questions is that how can i use the same port for both?..or is that even possible?

**Update 3**: Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your program.cs file - and are you using spa ?

Comment: @RahulSwamynathan Yes, this is a SPA. I have updated the question with `Program.cs`

Comment: Do you enable developer exception pages? 500 error can hide behind 404

Comment: How you configure the `Startup` ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the reason for this *issue*, but forgot to update here. My apologies.

Angular CLI is always run on a separate port. Let's assume your ASP.NET is listening on port 5000 and your Angular CLI is on 4200. Now if you are trying to call a Web API from Angular, you are looking at the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem.

### How i solved my problem

- Enable CORS in ASP.NET Core by following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instructions.
- From Angular, if you make a call to `api/controller/action/id`, it
  will prefix the route with `http://localhost:4200/` for you and that port does not
  have ASP.NET. So i hijacked the calls and conditionally re-routed the
  calls to port 5000 based on the `environment.production` (defined in `\environments\environment.ts`)

Hope this helps!